# Data needed for wolf habitat/potential distribution in Pacific NW region

Tags: data

Hello fellow GIS’ers,

I am assisting a nature writer with maps for a book he’s writing on wolves in the Pacific NW (Titled “Wolves in the Land of Salmon”).  I’m writing therefore in the hopes that some of you may know where I can find spatial data on wolves.  My hope is to map wolf subspecies ranges, source populations and regional dispersal corridors, regional historic and current wolf ranges, and projected regional population hubs.  I know of a few habitat suitability studies that have been undertaken (i.e.  Washington Fish&Game, Carrol et al) but so far have been unable to track down much useful GIS data.

I apologize for any cross posting.

Thanks in advance to any leads any of you may have!

Answer (score 2):

You may check with a Forest Service (Sawtooth National Forest) office in Idaho, or with the Nature Conservancy (TNC) in Idaho.  Both entities have dabases where this species is tracked; from there you could download the data.  TNC may not share this data, however.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try the R project forums.
we get a few questions here but I see many habitat/geostatistics related question on the [R-SIG-GEO list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-geo)
Also in the stackexchange section of this website there is an [R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).
However I was unable to return anything with a search of R and Wolves.
Don't get me wrong.
GIS people have data, it's just that statisticians have data you might be looking for (IMHO).